# How do we translate "3P vs. 1P" into Brazilian Portuguese financial/business/sales terms?"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, tradução

I know what it means in English, but I need to explain this next week to a group of Brazilian Portuguese speakers only and since I don't know how it's more commonly used in Brazil, perhaps someone here can help me. For instance, how do I put this into Brazilian Portuguese:

> Pricing: 3P vs. 1P – deep understanding of pricing
>
> - Do by category
> - Where do the sites overlap, and where don’t they? When does price matter less? When more?
> - Will 1P cannibalize 3P?  Does it depend on category, How does a merchant decide?
> - How do they handle 3P delivery?

I don't need a literal translation. If you need to elaborate a bit into Portuguese to make the translation better, that will totally suffice the need.

Comment: I am so happy for you! I know things like In Q2 or Q4, but I have never seen this 3 P versus 1 P.  How about you explain it?

Comment: What do you mean? It's not really hard..  there's a google article on it.. let me grab it for you

Comment: here: https://www.prospershow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/2016-Vendor-Central-or-Seller-Central-The-Tradeoffs-of-a-1P-vs-3P-Strategy-on-Amazon.pdf    but a lot of people are dealing with amazon when explaining/discussing this but simply disregard Amazon from the picture as it can be applied to any..

Comment: Valeu, veja abaixo. Acho que sim, há de traduzir o treco. :)

Comment: I agree with Lambie: you should probably explain in your question the meaning of 1P and 3P.

Comment: Nah.. it would be too tiring and beyond the need. Explanation already in the link I provided. Hugo already provided an excellent response. thanks guys!

Comment: Look, Hugo, you come and ask a question as if it was some usual thing. then you choose an answer that says that 3P can be translated as marketplace. That is simply wrong. Boa sorte. Credo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1P** can be translated as **venda direta**. It literally means "direct sale": a company selling directly to its consumers.

**3P** can be "translated" as **[Marketplace](https://ecommercenews.com.br/artigos/cases/e-marketplace-o-melhor-custo-beneficio-para-iniciar-um-e-commerce)**. I know, it's not in Portuguese, but it's the word being used by [B2W](https://www.b2wmarketplace.com.br/#/cadastro-parceiro/como-funciona) (and [other players](http://www.profissionaldeecommerce.com.br/o-que-netshoes-pode-ensinar-aos-lojistas-de-marketplace/)) to describe a system where a third-party sells the product using another party's infrastructure:

> O B2W Marketplace é uma plataforma que permite que você venda seus produtos nas vitrines da Americanas.com, Submarino e Shoptime. A B2W funciona como um mediador entre você e o cliente, oferecendo o tráfego mais qualificado da internet brasileira e a melhor experiência de compra.
>
> **Free translation**: B2W Marketplace is a platform that allows you to sell your products at Americanas.com, Submarino and Shoptime. B2W works as a mediator between you and the client, offering the most qualified traffic of brazilian internet and the best shopping experience.

---

Notes:

- In the corporate world (at least in Brazil) it's very common to use English words to describe something instead of trying to find a proper translation. And it seems to be the case with **Marketplace** - I believe that's because [Amazon also uses this word](https://developer.amazonservices.com/) and nobody could find a good translation to Portuguese.
- I've also seen **[Programa de afiliados](http://www.afiliados.com.br/faq.php?interna=1.2.#1.2.)** being used, by I think it works in a different way if compared to a **Marketplace**. And I think that [**Marketplace** fits better](http://www.jornalcruzeiro.com.br/materia/708901/empresas-de-sorocaba-aderem-ao-marketplace-e-alavancam-vendas) to Amazon's definition.
- I think it also depends on your audience (if the term is familiar to them). If it's not the case, you can use **venda por terceiros** (third party sales). Although I personally don't like it, I believe you'll be understood.

Comment: Thank you! And the explanation is excellent! The B2W example was perfect and nailed all my doubts,  in fact it relates to my needs. Thank you Hugo! haha.. I never expected to replying to someone with my name on SE PT! :D  

Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, for me it's unexpected to find someone with the same name - I've met only a few in my life; in this site I think you're the first one.

Comment: No, 3 P is not marketplace. It means to be a third party vendor. Marketplace is not a translation into Portuguese anyway. Seria um erro tremendo chamar 3P um marketplace. The translation into Portuguese is: vender como terceira parte. Não é venda POR terceiros nesse caso: Eu posso vender a Amazon como Primeria Parte (se eu tiver um contrato com ela); ou posso vender como Vendedor de Terceria Parte (Amazon e seus clientes seriam a premeira e segundo parte) e eu um Vendedor de Terceira Parte. É sé ler o inglês bem.

Comment: @Lambie I agree that "Marketplace" is not a literal translation *per se* and your answer is also correct. But I wrote my answer based on the link provided by the OP, and tried to come up with a word that could best translate the concept in this specific context ("Sell third-party to consumers through the Amazon marketplace" as stated in OP's link) instead of being too literal (so IMO both our answers are correct, I just took a different approach). I also considered that many players are using the same word for similar (if not the same) concept. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in my answer.

Comment: One more thing: that's why I put **"translated"** in double quotes

Comment: @Hugo, por favor. Não funciona como tradução. O português, sobre tudo no Brasil, já ficou cheio de coisas ridículas. Eis uma oportunidade de contribuir algo que tenha sentido....marketplace just means mercado. No fundo, não tem nada a ver com uma possível tradução de 1P e 3P.

Answer (score 1):

Se traduz assim:

Vender como parte primeira, ou vender diretamente, venda direta (entre você como primeira parte e Amazon Retail como segunda parte). Fez-se da frase um VERBO: to sell first-party to Amazon Retail: vender COMO primeira-parte à Amazon Retail.

Vender como terceira parte, vender indiretamente, venda indireta (você vende para eles, eles vendem ao público, eles e o público têm um contrato, daí você seria um terceiro, seriam a primeira e segunda parte, e você a terceira parte).

Esse inglês, *to sell third party to*, não é muito bom. O bom inglês diria: to sell AS a first or second party. Com o ***as*** na frase.

Vender como parte terceira e vender como parte primeira: parte 1.ª e parte 3ª.

Só que falando, há que dizer primeira e terceira.

[[Olha, por causa da eleições na França, tomei uns copos de vinho e não sei se a minha resposta ficou clara. Espero que sim.]]